# Aws Load balancer Internal vs External

Tags: amazon-web-services, internal-load-balancer

I would like to know if there is any difference between AWS's internal load balance and external load balancer besides the fact that only clients on the VPC can communicate with the internal load balancer.
Is there any perfomance difference like one of them answering faster or one of them being cheaper?
The only difference I could think of would be the internal load balancer making the data transfer cheaper.

Answer (score 0):

[An internal load balancer is assigned to a private subnet and does not have a public IP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-internal-load-balancers.html). It cannot be accessed by a client not on the VPC (even if you create a Route53 record pointing to it). If you want clients to be able to connect to your load balancer who are not on the VPC, you need to set up an internet-facing load balancer.

```
An internal load balancer routes traffic to your EC2 instances in private subnets. The clients must have access to the private subnets.
```

Comment: I already know this. My question is if there are other differences besides the one you mentioned.

Comment: No there is no other difference.